# There is no phonenumber.pb.h in libphonenumber

Tags: c++, libphonenumber

There is no *phonenumber.pb.h* and *phonemetadata.pb.h* in the [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/)(CPP) lib

So is there any way to find them out?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you actually build the library?  It appears those files are generated by protocol buffers as part of the build process.

Answer (score 1):

These are files generated by [Google protobuffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html) library from a simple .proto file that describes the protocol messages.

Check out the library sources, there should be `phonemetadata.proto` and `phonenumber.proto`